# How to correctly get an old question / issue noticed here on meta?

Tags: support, meta

I recently [noticed 'flickering tabs'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117899/flickering-tabs). After I posted that question I saw it was [a dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15457/tabs-flicker-when-mouse-over-top-edge).

However that question / issue was never resolved (it's a two year old question).

What does that mean?

1. It will not get fixed (shouldn't it get [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined))
2. People 'forgot' about that issue. And if this is the case what's the proper way of getting it noticed again? (I think I have effectively done that right now :P, but what should I have done)

   - Set a bounty on the question
   - Edit the question to bump it (don't think so, because the question is clear the way it is)
   - Something else?

Comment: Are you still using a Firefox 3 browser, like the OP of the dupe was?

Comment: @Mat It happens on all browsers. At least the ones I've tested it on. Chrome canary and stable and IE9

Comment: Ok, managed to reproduce - but seriously, is this really bothering you  in any important way whatsoever?

Comment: @Mat If you read my [original question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117899/flickering-tabs) you see I don't think it is a big issue, but it is an issue nonetheless. Which could have been fixed in two years time IMHO.

Comment: @Mat - Now that I know it's there, it really bother me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process for getting an old question on a meta site noticed is not different from what is done for a question on the main site.

- You edit the question to make it appear in the front page.
- You offer a bounty.

Between the two options, the first has the shorter effect: When new questions are posted, the question you wanted to get noticed will vanish again between the other questions. On Meta Stack Overflow, where fewer questions are posted, that question will be noticeable for a longer time.
With the second option, the question will be listed in the "featured" tab until the bounty expires, which means (if I am not wrong) seven days.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing that I am aware of internally to Meta...Although:

You could always share that post on respective social networks to spread word and attract new found attention.

**The best way** to gain attention to a post is by offering a bounty.

Like you said, the question doesn't need editing so it should not be edited.