# Pressing the Enter key in "Search the Help Center" in Contact Us page causing undesired result

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, contact

There is a nice "widget" in the [contact us page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) letting the user search the help center:

> [image]

When clicking the "search" button it works flawlessly and give back the results below the textbox.

However, if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the page posts back to itself, adding "?q=[search term]" to the URL of the contact page itself e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact?q=questions which of course is not the desired action.

Can the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press cause the search button to be clicked instead?

Comment: reproduced, looking at it...

Comment: @Doorknob oh you don't want to see me clicking a key! ;)

Comment: @ShaWiz Haha :P I didn't think anyone would read that edit comment :P

Comment: @Doorknob here on Meta the users read EVERYTHING. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in revision 2013.7.23.1258 (meta) / 2013.7.22.882 (sites)

Comment: Cheers, just hope your fix won't conflict with [Oded's fix](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189999/152859)! ;)