# Search the Help Center in Contact Support lists "more-results" twice

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, design, help-center

When using the search in [Contact Support](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and searching a value (like "ask") that returns too many results to display, the link (`15 results in the help center`) to the help center is displayed twice.

The HTML contains the element

```
<p class="more-results">15 results in the <a href="/help/search?q=ask">help center</a>.</p>
```

twice

[image]

Comment: @Oded this is specific to the new contact page, think we should add [meta-tag:contact-page] tag to avoid confusion with the act of contacting the team?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - not sure this is needed yet. The context of the question is clear here.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure it's a new bug as I would have seen it when reporting [this other bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189960/152859). (that was fixed quickly :))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fine then! We'll remove those extra results in the next build.  We just try and give you all the help we can, *twice* the help in some cases but *noooooooo* you guys don't want it!

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed-completed] ;)