# Mobile theme not showing when badge was awarded in per-user display

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, mobile-web

When viewing the per-user badge page, it's showing whether that user earned the badge or not and if earned, time when it was awarded. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1286/archaeologist?userid=2683).

On the mobile theme though, it's showing everything except the time when it was awarded:

> [image]

To compare, here's how it looks in the full version:

> [image]

Worth to mention that for badges awarded more than once it's showing the time awarded fine.

Comment: Worth to mention that the giant "S" came again with 1 in the mobile theme.

Comment: @hims056 yeah, I already gave up on this. :[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be deployed in `rev. 1894` (meta) and `rev. 1331` (network).

Comment: Thanks, but there's still a bug in there dunno if old or new. See [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49cfR6oO3Ig), it's the same root cause as the bug [reported here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15457/tabs-flicker-when-mouse-over-top-edge). Should I start new bug report?