# When signing in, clicking some of the buttons highlights them, setting off the others

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-interface, login

More of a cosmetic issue here, but when signing in you can choose from options such as Google, Facebook, Yahoo and Stack Exchange. Now when clicking one of these, a highlight box is set around the clicked item. Unfortunately this makes all items to the right of it move up a couple of pixels, and it annoys me sooooo much.

Of course after you click it you are redirected to the corresponding login, but you can still see it a few seconds before it redirects, and if you go back a page it's also still highlighted.

Here's an image of the before- and after clicking the Google-button: [image: the issue]

Comment: I... I don't really understand the problem of a button that moves a few pixels

Comment: Well isn't that an issue? Doesn't seem like a feature if elements of the page are moved around and not aligned properly with the other elements. Of course I could be mistaken.

Comment: I actually disagree that this is definately a bug.  Looking at how the UI behaves, it almost looks like this might have been an intentional design trying to make the button look 3D, or at least like it is "popping out" when selected.

Comment: I think [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VEK1vvLpY14) is a worse bug... can be reproduced even when already logged in by browsing to the [login page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/login). Same problem as [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15457/152859). (CSS issue)

Comment: This is a non-issue. That some buttons move a bit? This has no other visual impact and zero functional issue.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with those considering this "minor" that it is and should be given appropriate low priority in the grand scheme of things.

However, that is not to say that it should never be logged as an issue or intended to be fixed at some point, not only from an OCC QA perspective, but also that of a programmer.

Though I don't consider myself to be a "proper" programmer yet, I was reading some development philosophy recently which emphasized that in software development, any and all bugs should be resolved in order to ensure a predictable, stable piece of software. Any unexpected glitches could lead to others.