# My sock is having some layout issues

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design

My sock account tried to add a comment, which it obviously can't since it doesn't have much reputation (yet).

The 'error notification' lacks a nice font and is positioned too far to the right:

> [image]

The missing layout is also a problem with the same tool tips on various places, like the log in screen.

Can this be fixed? My sock says *pretty please*.

Comment: Same font is used in [golden badge close tooltip](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287473/339911).

Comment: Yes, I remember now. Thanks. @alexolut

Comment: maybe your sock is too smelly for the notification to get anywhere near it.

Comment: I somewhat agree @Cai, but the font is still different. There might be another issue with it too.

Comment: Since apparently my non-auto-possible-dupe comment was deleted: the font issue is a duplicate of [Missing font on some error and dupehammer info popups](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285049/missing-font-on-some-error-and-dupehammer-info-popups).

Comment: I suspect the positioning is intentional (just badly chosen)

Comment: @Cai huh, weird... how it got deleted?

Comment: @Sha no idea... it was deleted at the same time as this was closed as a dupe so I guess the system got confused and thought it was an auto-dupe comment. (seems I was right: [Possible Duplicate comment deletion is over-zealous](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195652/possible-duplicate-comment-deletion-is-over-zealous))

Comment: @Cai huh, right! You had the word "duplicate" in your comment?

Comment: @Sha yep. I think it was identical to my above comment ("the font issue is a duplicate of...").

Comment: @Cai so cruel... this should really be fixed. *going to place a bounty* :)

Comment: @Oded is this really completed? If so why the dupe target isn't tagged as well? :/

Comment: Missed the dupe, @Sha

Comment: Downvoted because dupe.